Galois automorphisms preserve discrete valuation?
I have a question re Cassels-Fröhlich Algebraic Number Theory, Chapter I. On p.19 there is a Corollary to 5, Proposition 3 stating:

Corollary. The element norm yields a commutative diagram (with exact rows)
$$ \require{AMScd} 
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> U_L @>>> L^\times @>{v_L}>> \mathbb Z @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VV{N_{L/K}}V @VV{f}V @.\\
0 @>>> U_K @>>> K^\times @>{v_K}>> \mathbb Z @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
i.e. $fv_L(x) = v_K(N_{L/K}(x))$ and $N_{L/K}(\mathfrak P) = \mathfrak p^f$.

where $L/K$ is a finite separable extension of complete, discretely valued fields, $U_{\bullet}$ denotes the unit group, $\mathfrak P$ is the valuation ideal in $L$, and $\mathfrak p$ is the valuation ideal in $K$.
This is presented as a corollary to $[L:K] = ef$, and stated immediately after $v_L(x) = ev_K(x)$. I couldn't quite figure out the proof. The proof stated was, in entirety:

$N_{L/K}(U_L) \subseteq U_K$ and $N_{L/K} \circ j = [L:K]$. $\Box$

Here, $j:K^\times \to L^\times$ denotes the natural inclusion. I understand these points, and I can see how the first indicates that the arrow $U_L \to U_K$ is well-defined, but I fail to see how this, coupled with the proposition, gives a full proof of the fact. I tried to continue the proof:
Let $\pi_L, \pi_K$ be uniformisers for $L,K$ respectively, then we have that $\mathfrak P = \pi_L \mathcal O_L$ and $\mathfrak p = \pi_K \mathcal O_K$. Hence
$$ \mathfrak p^{ef} = \pi_K^{[L:K]}\mathcal O_K = N_{L/K}(\pi_K \mathcal O_L) = N_{L/K}(\pi_L^e \mathcal O_L) = N_{L/K}(\mathfrak P)^e, $$
and so $N_{L/K}(\mathfrak P) = \mathfrak p^f$.
From here, I couldn't complete the proof of $fv_L(x) = v_K(N_{L/K}(x))$ without assuming that $v_L$ is invariant under Galois automorphisms and that $L/K$ is Galois (i.e. $|\textrm{Gal}(L/K)| = [L:K]$). The proof I ended up writing was:
Let $\alpha \in L^\times$. Writing $G=\textrm{Gal}(L/K)$ we have that
$$v_K(N_{L/K}(\alpha)) = \frac{1}{e} v_L\left( \prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(\alpha) \right) = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{\sigma \in G}v_L(\sigma(\alpha)) = \frac{1}{e} \sum_{\sigma \in G}v_L(\alpha) = \frac{|G|}{e}v_L(\alpha) = fv_L(\alpha).$$
My question is whether these are correct assumptions to make? If so, how can I prove these are in fact the case? If not, how does the proof stated in the book actually prove the corollary?
(First time posting a question here -- hope this is alright!)

for the question in the title: the extension of the valuation from $K$ to $L$ is unique, so it is preserved by $Gal(L/K)$

The valuation $v_L$ is indeed invariant under Galois automorphisms – this is a basic fixture of the theory of non-Archimedean local fields (the point is that, as stated in the comments, valuations extend uniquely along finite extensions).
I’m not sure you can assume $L/K$ to be Galois, though – the natural idea would to consider a Galois extension $M \subset L$, and show that the result for the Galois extensions $M/L, M/K$ implies the conclusion for $L/K$, but I’m not sure.
But your argument doesn’t really need the assumption that $L/K$ is Galois. Indeed, let $M$ be the Galois closure of $L/K$, then, for $x \in L^{\times}$,
$$v_K(N_{L/K}(x))=e_{M/K}^{-1}v_M(N_{L/K}(x))=e_{M/K}^{-1}v_M(\prod_{\sigma \in Hom_K(L,M)}{\sigma(x)})=e_{M/K}^{-1}\sum_{\sigma \in Hom_K(L,M)}{v_M(\sigma(x))}=e_{M/K}^{-1}\sum_{\sigma \in Gal(M/K)/Gal(M/L)}{v_M(\sigma(x))}=e_{M/K}^{-1}\sum_{\sigma \in Gal(M/K)/Gal(M/L)}{v_M(x)}=[L:K]e_{M/L}e_{M/K}^{-1}v_L(x)=f_{L/K}v_L(x).$$
Here is the argument that Cassels-Frohlich meant, though.
Because $N_{L/K}(U_L) \subset U_K$, for $x \in L^{\times}$, $v_K(N_{L/K}x)$ is a function $\alpha: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ of $v_L(x)$.
Because $v_L, v_K \circ N_{L/K}: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ are group homomorphisms, $\alpha$ is a group homomorphism, so can be written as $n \mapsto an$ for some integer $a$.
In other words: for any $x \in L^{\times}$, one has $v_K(N_{L/K}x)=av_L(x)$. Take $x \in K^{\times}$ with nonzero valuation, then $av_L(x)=ae_{L/K}v_K(x)$ and $av_L(x)=v_K(N_{L/K}x)=v_K(x^{[L:K]})=[L:K]v_K(x)$, whence $ae_{L/K}=[L:K]$ and $a=f_{L/K}$, QED.

Ah, thank you! You've really cleared it up :)
